# Not getting a Valid JSON Respon from magento2 custom API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, json, webapi, json-response

I am trying to return the collection factory from database , it is giving an array now i convert it to json using JSON Encode function but it is returnig a string with backslashes !!

**Code for Api Interface**

```
<?php
namespace FME\MobileApp\Api;
interface SliderInterface
{
    /**
 * @return Object
 */
public function getImages();

}
```

**Code for API**

```
<?php
namespace FME\MobileApp\Model\Api;
use \FME\MobileApp\Model\ImgFactory;
class SliderImages {
    protected $modelFactory;
    public $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
    ImgFactory $modelFactory ,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager 
)
 {
    $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;

    }
    
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getImages()
{
    $baseurl =  $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

    $photogallery_id = 1;

    $model = $this->modelFactory->create()->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToFilter('photogallery_id',$photogallery_id);
    
    $results = $model->getData();
    

        return json_encode($results);
 }
```

}

**Output**

"[{"img_id":"1","img_name":"\/6\/1\/619c5e9c0fe4d_6.jpg","img_label":"","img_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/m2422\/pub\/media\/mobapp\/images\/6\/1\/619c5e9c0fe4d_6.jpg","photogallery_id":"1","img_order":"1","disabled":"0","img_description":"","tags":""}]"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use code like this one.

```
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class SliderImages 
{
    protected $serialize;

    public function __construct(Json $serialize)
    {
        $this->serialize = $serialize;
    }

    public function getImages()
    {
        $results = $model->getData();
        return $this->serialize->serialize($results);
    }

}
```